# (g)awk: Substituting expression from another script

Tags: awk, gawk

I am building a generic script which will be re-used from several other scripts.
For each case, I need to extract Nth field in the generic script; in some cases the double quotes should be removed from that script. The field delimiter also varies from case to case.

Ideally I would like to simply pass an entire `awk` statement to the generic script, like this:

script1.sh:

```
 generic_script.sh "{print $1}"
```

script2.sh:

```
 generic_script.sh "BEGIN {FS=","} {gsub(/"/, "", $1);  print $1}"
```

generic_script.sh

```
 awk_expression="$1"
 awk '$awk_expression' file_to_process.txt
```

(I intentionally omitted escaping of `"` and `$` in script2.sh for the sake of readibility of this question).

What is "proper enough" way to make such a generic script, and also to provide right arguments in these two scripts?

Both `awk` and `gawk` are available for me; I'm on MacOS HighSierra 10.13.6.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Both `awk "$1" file` or `a=$1; awk "$a" file` in `generic_script.sh` should be fine. Read about the difference between `'` and `"` quoting -- you shouldn't escape anything in `script2.sh` but to quote using `'`: `generic_script 'BEGIN{ ... $1 ...}'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should cover it.

```
$ cat generic_script.sh
#!/bin/bash
awk_expression="$1"
awk "$awk_expression" file_to_process.txt
$ cat file_to_process.txt
"foo","bar"
$ ./generic_script.sh '{ print $1 }'
"foo","bar"
$ ./generic_script.sh 'BEGIN {FS=","} {gsub(/"/, "", $1);  print $1}'
foo
$
```

Comment: The problem is that I also need to support script2.sh, which requires to set input field separator, and to remove quotes around the selected field :-)

Comment: Yes, works for that, example added.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Looks like I messed up something with how quoting works in sh.